# How can I align an <h1> to the center and a <p> to the right in the same div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 to come up with a div that would contain an `<h1>` aligned to the center while a `<p>` tag aligned to the right. Here is exactly what I am trying to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhgqX.jpg

I would prefer a method using the bootstrap 4 classes or flexbox rather than using any floats. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 p-20">
        <h1 class="heading-font px36-font d-inline-block">.Hay<span class="skyblue">ford</span></h1>
        <p class="d-inline-block special-font b-900"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +92-336-54-14-994</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rob Thanks! That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 p-20">
    <h1 class="heading-font px36-font d-inline-block">.Hay<span class="skyblue">ford</span></h1>
    <p class="d-inline-block special-font b-900"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +92-336-54-14-994</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But it doesn't push the <p> tag towards the right? Does it?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Sadly, this won't work. The reason for this not working is that both the h1 and p tags are inline block elements and don't really span the whole width of the div for the alignments to work.

Comment: H1 and P are block elements by default.  Seems the solution is to not redefine them as inline-block as you're apparently doing.

Answer (score 0):

Just dividing the main div into 2 sub divs

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 p-20">
                <div style="width: 80%; float:left">
                <center><h1 class="heading-font px36-font d-inline-block">.Hay<span class="skyblue">ford</span></h1></center>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 20%; float:right">
                <p class="d-inline-block special-font b-900"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +92-336-54-14-994</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The `<center>` element has been obsolete for three years now and deprecated before that: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for the new update. It's been years since the last time I use html. I just use which I studied many years ago

Answer (score -1):

For the h1 you can add a class called "text-center".
For the parent div "p-20" make it relative.
Now,
Position the p tag as absolute and control it using right: 5px;, top: 5px;.

Hope this works, do vote if it was help full.

Thank you..!!